# How to start WSL terminal in a current powershell directory?

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can open a powershell and type

```
> Ubuntu
```

to open a WSL ubuntu shell on windows 10. This will always take me to the WSL home directory. How would I instead open the terminal in the same location that the powershell is currently in?

FYI. I need this for creating a right click "open terminal here" type registery key for windows explorer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we look at what running `ubuntu.exe` actually does:

```
PS C:\> ubuntu.exe /?
Launches or configures a Linux distribution.

Usage:
    <no args>
        Launches the user's default shell in the user's home directory.

    install [--root]
        Install the distribution and do not launch the shell when complete.
          --root
              Do not create a user account and leave the default user set to root.

    run <command line>
         Run the provided command line in the current working directory. If no
         command line is provided, the default shell is launched.

    config [setting [value]]
        Configure settings for this distribution.
        Settings:
          --default-user <username>
              Sets the default user to <username>. This must be an existing user.

    help
        Print usage information.
```

We can see that it by default launches the WSL shell inside the *home directory*. If we want run inside it inside the current directory open in PowerShell, we need to specify the `run` option. So the full command will be `ubuntu.exe run`.

Another option is to just run `wsl.exe` or `bash.exe`. These commands will by default open WSL in the current working directory.

**Note:** We don't need to specify the `.exe` after the commands. Running `ubuntu`, `wsl` and `bash` all work as well. PowerShell knows how to run executables without specifying the extension.

Answer (score 8):

method 1:

- set Ubuntu to wsl default distribution by `wsl --set-default Ubuntu`
- just type wsl and you are in the current Powershell directory

method 2:

open other folder

- `wsl.exe --cd $pwd` or `wsl.exe --cd "path"`

[image]

[image]