# From command line to start Windows Terminal and set current directory to a specific folder for Ubuntu profile

Tags: windows-terminal

From command line, I can use following command

```
wt.exe -d "C:\Program Files"
```

to open **Windows Terminal** and set the current directory to "C:\Program Files" folder, if Windows Terminal's default profile is **cmd**, or **Windows PowerShell**.

But if the default profile is **Ubuntu**, the above command can open Windows Terminal, but the current directory is $HOME, not **/mnt/c/Program Files** (the Linux path).

Someone said when they tried this command, they can get current directory to /mnt/c/Program Files folder. But I always get into $HOME directory. I am wondering if I set something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Ubuntu WSL profile in Windows Terminal uses the `ubuntu.exe` executable as the shell. However, this command always starts the terminal in the `$HOME` path.

To allow the terminal to open in a given starting directory, add `run` to the starting command line.  Here's the resulting profile:

```
{
    "commandline": "ubuntu.exe run",
    "guid": "{51855cb2-8cce-5362-8f54-464b92b32386}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "source": "CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc"
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12961)

Comment: wow, spend a day for this. saved me

Comment: where you find that we have to use `run`. I was trying all sorts of things. but no luck

Comment: thanks a lot for this..very important, will save a lot of time for me

Comment: @Santhosh I found out about run here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61073056/973624

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `settings.json` and for  the default ubuntu profile make sure you something like this:

```json
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
                "startingDirectory": "C:\\Program Files"
```

Comment: I still entered HOME directory.